# Does coprimality lead to subvarieties of codimension not less than 2?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{A}^n(k) $ be an affine variety over a field $k$ and $ f,g \in k[X]$ two regular functions on $X$.
If we now assume $f$ and $g$ to be coprime and define $Y := \mathcal{V}(f,g)$ as their zero locus, then (why) does $ \text{codim}_X Y \geq 2$ hold ?

Lets not make life complicated and assume $X$ to be irreducible, then $\dim \mathcal{V}(h) < \dim X$, with $h \in \{ f,g\}$ follows immedieatly, as $h$ cannot be constant on $X$. Therefore it should suffice to show $ \dim Y < \dim \mathcal{V}(h) $. However, this is where i am stuck as i am unable to see why the contrary would contradict the coprimality of $f$ and $g$.

There may be additional conditions required, but i am quite sure to have seen statements similar to this used in literature.

Comment: What is your definition of "coprime"?

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, i only know of the following definition:
Two elements $a,b$ in a ring $R$ are said to be coprime if their only common factors are units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true if $f$ and $g$ are "coprime" in the sense that for any $h$, if $f$ divides $gh$, then $f$ divides $h$.  This means that $g$ is a non-zero divisor mod $f$, so it is not contained in any minimal prime of $k[X]/(f)$.  Thus every prime of $k[X]/(f,g)$ must have height at least $1$ when lifted back to a prime of $k[X]/(f)$, and so must have height at least $2$ when lifted back to a prime of $k[X]$.  Thus, every chain of prime ideals in $k[X]/(f,g)$ can be extended to a chain of length $2$ more in $k[X]$, so $\dim k[X]/(f,g)\leq \dim k[X]-2$.

(It does not suffice to assume that $f$ and $g$ have no nonunit common factors.  For instance, let $X\subset\mathbb{A}^3$ be the surface defined by $xy-z^2=0$.  Then $x$ and $z$ have no nonunit common factors in $k[X]=k[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)$, but setting $x=z=0$ does not constrain the value of $y$, so the zero locus of $x$ and $z$ in $X$ is a line, which has codimension $1$.)

Comment: Thank you a lot, that was really helpful !